# How to import com.sun.mdm.index.query.QueryObject

Tags: java, gradle

In my java project I want to use the `com.sun.mdm.index.query.QueryObject` [class](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18150_01/javadocs/SunMasterIndex/com/sun/mdm/index/query/QueryObject.html). I tried

```
import com.sun.mdm.index.query.QueryObject;
```

But I got compile error

> package com.sun.mdm.index.query does not exist

What dependencies do I need to include in gradle to be able to use this class.

Comment: This seems an XY-problem. Do you really want / need to develop a "Sun Master Index" application? Did you read the [Before You Begin Developing a Master Index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3375/dsgn_eview-prep_c/index.html) page?

Comment: @ThomasKläger Lol. I didn't know it was part of something. I now know the context of the class. I have decided it's not worth importing it.